# Displaying CP437 ('extended ascii') in Perl/Gtk

Tags: perl, gtk, ascii

Is there any way in which I can display old-fashioned extended ASCII (cp437) in a Gtk2::TextView? (Google suggests no answers.)

If there is some way of changing the charset used by a GTK widget, I can't find it.

Or maybe it's necessary to use Perl's Encode module, as I tried in the script below, but that doesn't work either.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Display ASCII

use strict;
use diagnostics;
use warnings;
use Encode;

use Glib qw(TRUE FALSE);
use Gtk2 '-init';

# Open a Gtk2 window, with a Gtk2::TextView to display text
my $window = Gtk2::Window->new('toplevel');
$window->set_title('Extended ASCII viewer');
$window->set_position('center');
$window->set_default_size(600, 400);
$window->signal_connect('delete-event' => sub {

    Gtk2->main_quit();
    exit;
});

my $scrollWin = Gtk2::ScrolledWindow->new(undef, undef);
$window->add($scrollWin);
$scrollWin->set_policy('automatic', 'automatic');     
$scrollWin->set_border_width(0);

my $textView = Gtk2::TextView->new;
$scrollWin->add_with_viewport($textView);
$textView->can_focus(FALSE);
$textView->set_wrap_mode('word-char');
$textView->set_justification('left');
my $buffer = $textView->get_buffer();

$window->show_all();   

# In cp437, this is a series of accented A characters
my $string = chr (131) . chr (132) . chr (133) . chr (134);

# Display plain text
$buffer->insert_with_tags_by_name($buffer->get_end_iter(), $string . "\n");

# Display UTF-8 text
my $utfString = encode('utf8', $string);
$buffer->insert_with_tags_by_name($buffer->get_end_iter(), $utfString . "\n");

# Display cp437
my $cpString = decode ('cp437', $string);
my $utfString2 = encode('utf-8', $cpString);
$buffer->insert_with_tags_by_name($buffer->get_end_iter(), $utfString2 . "\n");

# Other suggestion
my $otherString = encode("utf-8", decode ("cp437", $string));
$buffer->insert_with_tags_by_name($buffer->get_end_iter(), $otherString . "\n");

# Directly decode a hex character (as suggested)
my $hexString = encode("utf-8", decode("cp437", "\xBA"));
$buffer->insert_with_tags_by_name($buffer->get_end_iter(), $hexString . "\n");

Gtk2->main();
```

[image]

Comment: How does it not work? You might want [edit] and include screenshots of your output, and a description of what it should look like.

Comment: If `insert_with_tags_by_name` expects decoded text, use `my $string = decode("cp437", "\xBA");`.

Comment: If `insert_with_tags_by_name` expects text encoded using UTF-8, use `my $string = encode("UTF-8", decode("cp437", "\xBA"));`.

Comment: (`BA` is the cp437 encoding of "║")

Comment: I tried that, with no success. Screenshot now appears above.

Comment: How about outputting `$cpString` (decoded cp437 output)?

Comment: I tried this on Ubuntu 17.10, and Perl `Gtk2` module version 1.24992 and I get the same result as you. However, if I encode as `latin1` instead of `utf-8` it works fine. I am not sure if this could be a bug in the Perl module or in Gtk

Comment: Very strange. I also see the correct characters if I encode in latin1, instead of utf-8.

However, not all characters are displayed as if we had encoded into utf-8. For example, the â character (134) is displayed correctly, but the ▓ shade character (177) is not, and neither are the pipe characters, for example ╟ (199).

Answer (score 6):

[Gtk wants to receive UTF-8 encoded strings](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/TextWidget.html), so anything you pass to a Gtk widget should be UTF-8 encoded.

If your input is `cp437`, then you'll want to decode it first and reencode it as UTF-8.

```
my $cp437_string = chr(153) x 10;               # cp437 encoded
my $string = decode('cp437', $cp437_string);    # Unicode code point encoded
my $utf8_string = encode('utf-8', $string);     # utf-8 encoded
$buffer->insert_with_tags_by_name(
    $buffer->get_end_iter(), $utf8_string . "\n");
```

Comment: Tried that too, see the edited script and screenshot above.

Answer (score 3):

Gtk2.pm expects Perl character strings (`Encode::decode(...)`), which are internally stored as UTF-8.

If you feed it a byte string (`Encode::encode(...)`), it will try to display it as latin1.

```
# In cp437, this is a series of accented A characters
my $string = chr (131) . chr (132) . chr (133) . chr (134);

my $perlString = decode ('cp437', $string);

$buffer->insert_with_tags_by_name($buffer->get_end_iter(), $perlString . "\n\n");


my $charmap = join("", map chr, 128..255);
$charmap =~ s!.{16}\K!\n!g;
$perlString = decode ('cp437', $charmap);

$buffer->insert_with_tags_by_name($buffer->get_end_iter(), $perlString . "\n");

Gtk2->main();
```

**Resulting screenshot**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for resolving this issue!

Comment: Tnx! Working in GTK3+ too.